# Validating nested models with ActiveModel::Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activemodel

My application uses plain Ruby classes with `ActiveModel::Validations`, without implementing `ActiveRecord`:

```
class Car
  include ::ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :engine
end

class Engine
  include ::ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :cylinders
  validates_presence_of :cylinders
end
```

I would like `Car` to check the nested attributes that are of `ActiveModel::Validations`, in this case `engine`.

```
car = Car.new
car.engine = Engine.new

car.engine.valid? # => false
car.valid?        # => true
                  # It should return 'false',
                  # because 'engine.cylinders' is 'nil'
```

What's the easiest way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

One option is creating your own validation method, something like

```
class Car
  include ::ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :engine

  validate :engine_must_be_valid

  def engine_must_be_valid
    errors.add(:base, "Engine is not valid") unless engine.valid?
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I wanted to nest the errors from `engine` into `car`s errors, but it seems like most people think that's an anti-pattern. This seems sufficient for the basic case I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

I use Gem [active_type](http://github.com/makandra/active_type) in almost all my projects for similar requirements. Project statement - Make any Ruby object quack like ActiveRecord. Project github page provides good documentation as well.

in your Gemfile, add:
`gem 'active_type'`

Then,

```
class Car < ActiveType::Object  

    nests_one :engine
    validates :check_engine

    def check_engine
        return true if self.engine.valid?
        false
    end
end

class Engine < ActiveType::Object

    attribute :cylinders, :string
    validates :cylinders, presence: true
end
```

Now,

```
car = Car.new
car.engine = Engine.new

car.engine.valid? # => false
car.valid?        # => false
```